# How to deserialize a simpe json array in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have a simple JSON array like this :

```
"{0: "4", 1: "5"}"
```

How can I deserialize this JSON array in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ASP.NET MVC applications use the [JSON.NET library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for that purpose. In that case you would do:

```
var numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>("{0: \"4\", 1: \"5\"}");
```